# How to write a command line script that will loop through every line in a text file and append a string at the end of each?

Tags: shell

I'm currently trying to write a command line script that will take a text file, go through every line in that file and append a string to it.

This is what I have so far but it failed to work:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/ConcatScript
for i in $( ls ); do
    SET $i + “,,1,,0”
done
```

I've been looking online but haven't found anything to help with this.

Comment: I'm unclear as to the question. Where do you want the output to go? Back to the original file? To a new file? To stdout? To somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @Tanktalus thanks for responding. I want the output to go back to the original file.